# problema al crear calculadora AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Tengo un problema al intentar crear o hacer una calculadora en Angular. Soy nuevo, apenas empiezo, me descargué un proyecto y al cargar no me sale como deberia v: 
no sé por que me sale parte del codigo en la ejecucción , revisé las rutas y todo parece bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Calculator</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="calculator/scripts/angularCalculator.js"></script>
        <link rel="src/styles.css" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="calculator" ng-controller="calculatorCtrl">
        <div class="whole-container">
            <div class="result-container">
                {{firstValue || 0 }}
                <span ng-if="currentModifier">{{currentModifier}}</span> 
                <span ng-if="secondValue">{{ secondValue }}</span>
                <span ng-if="result" class="result-item"> = {{ result }}</span>
                <button class="clear-button" ng-click="clearNumbers()">X</button>
            </div>
            <div class="number-modify-container">
                <div class="number-container">
                    <div class="number-inner-container" ng-repeat="num in numArr">
                        <button class="number-item"  ng-click="showNumber(num)">{{ num }}</button>
                        <button class="number-item" ng-if="$index == 9" ng-click="showNumber('.')"> . </button>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modify-container">
                    <button class="modify-item" ng-repeat="mod in modifiers" ng-click="makeSecondValue(mod)">{{ mod }}</button>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="result-button" ng-click="doMath()">=</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ejecutaste `ng serve -o` en la terminal?

Comment: ese es el resultado de la ejecución

Comment: Creo que lo mas probable es que por ahí tengas unas comillas o comilla que esta interfiriendo con el código?, talvez pueda ser.